# Is there any way for Windows 7 taskbar to show the index of each app?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

As you might know, the taskbar supports shortcuts like <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>. However I need to count the applications listed in the taskbar to find out the correct shortcut combination.

Is there any way for the Windows 7 taskbar to show the index of the application icon?

Comment: belongs to superuser

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it.

Since the purpose of these shortcuts is to enable you to switch between most commonly used applications, I honestly can't see why you would want this either; you can simply drag/pin the applications you use the most to the first few positions.

This will also make the indexes fixed for these applications, so you will simply remember the shortcuts.